# Mountpoint of Online Accounts

Tags: 19.10, rsync, online-accounts

I have added a google drive and a nextcloud online account to my Ubuntu 19.10. I want to auto sync some stuff with rsync, but I cant figure out where the folders of the online accounts are mounted.

Comment: I don't use those so I can't be sure, but check in `/run/user/1000/gvfs` That's where my click-to-mount Samba shares go. If you're not user 1000 adjust accordingly.

Comment: `df`, `mount` will tell you what's mounted, also `less /etc/mtab`.

Comment: @waltinator can't find it via this commands, is it possible that the online account data isn't mounted at all, but only accessed on demand if the user navigates there. Would be confusing, as the nautilus GUI really gives the impression that those shares are mounted.